# Trasform a Tuple to List of Objects with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Given a `List<Tuple>` from a class shaped like this:

```
class Tuple {
  String key,
  String key_key,
  String key_value
}
```

and given two classes:

```
class Mother {
  String key,
  List<Son> sons
}

class Son {
  String key,
  String value
}
```

which way I can map the tuples into the Mother class, for example:

```
k1, kk1, kv1
k1, kk1, kv2
k2, kk3, kv3
```

would result in:

```
k1 -> [[kk1, kv1], [kk1, kv2]]
k2 -> [[kk3, kv3]]
```

I'm completely confused between flatmap and collectors.

Comment: `flatMap` is the same as `map` except that the resulting type should specifically be a Stream, which is then "flattened". If you were to do a normal `map` with the same function, you would get a `Stream<Stream<...>>`, which is usually not what you want. The "flattening" is a kind of "unwrapping" of Stream of Streams into a single Stream of items. A Collector is an argument given to the terminal operation `collect` which accumulates the stream element into some value, like a List. They are very different things.

Comment: What did you try so far? Note that we're here to help with specific questions but we're not doing the work for you :)

Comment: In general you'll probably have to use a grouping collector in this case.

Comment: You need to use collecttors.

Collect to map in particular.

Comment: @thomas thank you. You're absolutely right, there are a lot of memes about questions like mine. (see the question score) The problem is that my codie didn't work at all, at the end I found one solution, but the accepted answer is much better than my messy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. group tuple List by key
2. map the to the object son
3. collect to list
4. convert map to a list of mothers

```java
Map<String, List<Son>> mapWithSons = tupleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.key, //1
                    Collectors.mapping(t -> new Son(t.key_key, t.key_value), //2
                       Collectors.toList()))); //3

List<Mother> motherList = mapWithSons.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new Mother(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())) //4
        .toList();
```

Comment: Thank you @frascu I was trying with

`Map<String, List<Tuple>> collect = tuples.stream().collect(groupingBy(Tuple::getKey));
  LinkedList<Mother> result = new LinkedList<>();
  collect.forEach((key, value) -> {
   Son son = new Son(key, new LinkedList<>());
   result.add(...`
and it works but it was too verbose, your solution it's much simple, concise, clear and it explains me lot of things. Thank you!